# I can see where is the error at .NET 6 JWT Authentication Minimal Api

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to start .NET 6 with this code, but is not going on, only return 401 Unauthorized, I not see where is the error.

All the code is in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(builder.Configuration["Jwt:SigningSecret"]))
                };
            });
```

add AddAuthorization

```
builder.Services.(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("user", policy => policy.RequireClaim("minimalapi", "user"));
    options.AddPolicy("admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("minimalapi", "user"));
});
```

Using both

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Require Authorization at  /myuser

```
app.MapGet("/myuser", () => "hi user!").RequireAuthorization("user");
```

```
So, created a gettoken url

app.MapPost("/token", (HttpContext http) =>
{
    var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim("name", "john"),
            new Claim("minimalapi", "user")
        };

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken
    (
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(60),
        notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(builder.Configuration["Jwt:SigningSecret"])), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    );

    http.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new { token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) });
});
```

Aways return "401 Unauthorized" (I'm sending the beaer token in the header)

Comment: Full code at https://pastebin.com/fuz4PmrV

Comment: I don' t like  notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow, remove it just for test. You should know that it can be usen in time before,  because the time is gone already.

Comment: @Serge I did remove "notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow" but, unsuccess.